# Тег, как сократить радиус

Tags: html, вёрстка

[image: Фото]

Мне надо уменьшить радиус, чтобы слева и справа при наведении нельзя было переходить по ссылке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дать этой ссылке

```
display: block;
width: 500px; // подобрать макс. ширину кликабельной области
margin: 0 auto;
```

Не проверял.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось))))

Answer (score 0):

Убрать у ссылки `display:block;`, добавить `text-align: center;`

Comment: Исправил ответ